# Own written Java Jira Module not working anymore after upgrade of Jira - Why does it fail?

Tags: java, jira, gerrit

for my work i have written a Gerrit Plugin for Jira-Tickets exist or not. Jira was upgraded from 7 to 8, i got some exceptions on my Java Tests in the Jira Module:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture, com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback)'
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of.then(Promises.java:249)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of.done(Promises.java:239)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of.fold(Promises.java:292)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.WrappingResponsePromise.transform(WrappingResponsePromise.java:25)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.callAndParse(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:138)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.callAndParse(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:152)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousSearchRestClient.searchJqlImplGet(AsynchronousSearchRestClient.java:109)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousSearchRestClient.searchJql(AsynchronousSearchRestClient.java:94)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousSearchRestClient.searchJql(AsynchronousSearchRestClient.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Does anyone have the same issue? Here are my gradle dependency list:

```
    implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    implementation group: 'com.atlassian.jira', name: 'jira-rest-java-client-api', version: '5.0.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'

    implementation group: 'io.atlassian.fugue', name: 'fugue', version: '4.7.1'
    implementation group: 'com.atlassian.jira', name: 'jira-rest-api', version: '8.13.22'
    implementation (group: 'com.atlassian.jira', name: 'jira-api', version: '8.13.22'){
        exclude group: 'jta'
    }


    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-jre'

    implementation 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:5.0.4'
    implementation 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:5.0.4'
    }
```

I have read in some github-posts that it could possible that the `guava`-library makes this problems, but i am not sure. An additional important information is that i am building a shadowJar, to have all libraries inside of the module.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Kind Regards

Siegfried

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot to show the source, where the exception raise. Here it is:

```public boolean existTicketId (String jiraID) {
        JiraRestClient jiraRestClient = getJiraRestClient();
        SearchRestClient searchClient = jiraRestClient.getSearchClient();
        String searchParameterKey="key=";
        boolean jiraIDexist = false;

        try {
          searchClient.searchJql(searchParameterKey + jiraID).claim();
          jiraIDexist = true;
        } ```

Comment: After restrict the version of guava from the latest to 20.0 the module, what produce a jar-file and the test works. But when i am integrating the shadow-jar-file in the gerrit-plugin, then i got the same error. In the jar-file of this plugin, i can see the folders and the files from guava, but as i said, when i roll it out and run the plugin with the check, it says SuchNoMethodError.